# Session variable always getting the same value

Tags: php, html, session, session-variables

I am using php to set the session variables for 21 districts in my web page. For this I am using the code bellow.

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Cache-control: private'); // IE 6 FIX

//DISTRITO
if (isSet($_GET['distrito'])) {
    $distrito = $_GET['distrito'];

// register the session
$_SESSION['distrito'] = $distrito;
}
else
{
$distrito = 'portugal';
}
?>
```

The problem is that in my pages, no matter what districts I choose it always assumes the same. Can anyone help me please?

http://codepen.io/Ryuh/pen/ZOYPmZ?editors=1000

Comment: isSet is incorrect. it's isset()

Comment: It was not it. It does the same thing. Can it be the html?

Answer (score 0):

Your wrote isset wrong. It's not isSet() it's isset(). Hope that works for you

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Cache-control: private'); // IE 6 FIX

//DISTRITO
if (isset($_GET['distrito'])) {
    $distrito = $_GET['distrito'];

// register the session
$_SESSION['distrito'] = $distrito;
}
else
{
$distrito = 'portugal';
}
?>
```

Comment: It was not it. It does the same thing. Can it be the html?

Comment: If you are asking about extension so it must be PHP.

Comment: Yeah, but it can be on the page itself

Comment: You can read this link as a reference

http://serverfault.com/questions/496773/how-to-get-the-php-code-working-inside-html-file

Comment: I know that. My question is: Can it be something wrong with my php on the index.php page? I think the variable is set correctly but when I echo it, it always shows the same content.

Comment: Yes,if you are getting same value that means there is something wrong where you are updating session.

Answer (score 0):

Typo there, replace isSet with [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) :

**PHP**

```
session_start();
header('Cache-control: private'); // IE 6 FIX
if (isset($_GET['distrito'])) {
    $distrito = $_GET['distrito'];
    $_SESSION['distrito'] = $distrito;
}
else {
 $distrito = 'portugal';
}
```

Comment: It was not it. It does the same thing. Can it be the html?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are aiming for:

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Cache-control: private'); // IE 6 FIX

//DISTRITO
if(isset($_GET['distrito']))
{
        $distrito = $_GET['distrito'];   
        // register the session
        $_SESSION['distrito'] = $distrito;
}
else
{
        if(isset($_SESSION['distrito']))
        {
                $distrito = $_SESSION['distrito'];
        }
        else
        {
                $distrito = 'portugal';
        }
}
```

This will use the GET variable first, and if that is not set it will look for the cookie value, then default to portugal if both of those are not set.